# Determine if app is Wayland or X client

Tags: wayland

Is there a way to determine if an arbitrary app is an X client or a Wayland client (or neither) from the command line without fully launching it?

Comment: It's worth noting that most programs use an external library for their interface (Gtk, Qt, SDL) and those can be clients of either, depending on how you configured them.

Answer (score 4):

You can run ldd on the binary to check which libraries it links against. If it has "libwayland-client" you're probably looking at a Wayland client. For X you need to look for "libX11" or "libxcb".

Comment: Interesting approach.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on the excellent answer given by @`Alexander Sukhoverkhov` what needs to be done is:

```
cd /usr/bin
ldd $application_name | grep wayland
```

Furthermore, to check which binaries have `wayland` support you could try:

```
cd /usr/bin
find . | xargs ldd | grep wayland -B 55
```

The above is not really very clean but it works. You can further pipe it to a file and then use `vim` to navigate.

```
cd /usr/bin
find . | xargs ldd | grep wayland -B 55 >> candidates
vim candidates
# Use vi movement
```

The `-B` flag stands for before and helps to print the binary name.

Comment: What about programs like Thunderbird, that support Wayland but can be run both as X or Wayland client?

Comment: That will be determined by the flags with which it was compiled and the default flags your OS uses. Typically it will always be X unless you have modified the environment variables globally. Personally I end up writing `.desktop` files for them. Great question @muzzle :)